# git-status does not reflect modified file

Tags: git, git-commit, git-status

Eventhough I have made unsaved changes to the README.md file, git status does not reflect modified file and instead says nothing to commit, why is this so?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Git operates on file system level, it does not know anything about your unsaved files in VSCode. Once you save the file, git will notice it as modified.